# Jquery and Bootstrap 4 - Navbar transitions for resize and scrolltop

Tags: jquery, html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

Hi so I am running into a roadblock that my beginner mind is unable to fix. Using Bootstrap 4 navbar and some jquery I was able to create a transition that turns an invisible navbar into a solid color when the user scrolls past a specific point. I tried to search for some hints and answers here but can't seem to find a solution. Here is my scroll code.

```
navScroll(){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if($(document).scrollTop() > 500) {
                $('.navbar').addClass('solid');
                $('.nav-link').addClass('black');
                $('.navbar-brand').addClass('black');
            }
            else{
                $('.navbar').removeClass('solid');
                $('.nav-link').removeClass('black');
                $('.navbar-brand').removeClass('black');
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Now when I resize the window width past 700 pixels, I wanted the navbar to turn a solid white and keep that way when scrolling up and down. Only when the window resizes outside 700 pixels will the JQ scroll code come back into play.

So I tried using this for the width resize:

```
navWidth(){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(window).resize(function() {
            if($(document).width() < 700){
                $('.navbar').addClass('solid');
                $('.nav-link').addClass('black');
                $('.navbar-brand').addClass('black');
            }
        })
    })
}
```

So this is where I got stuck on: I know that I need to do some kind of conditional but I am stuck how to proceed. Here is one thing I tried but failed (of course it failed but I wanted to see if it worked, and it did half-way but not the full extent).

```
navCheck(){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if($(document).width() < 700){
          $(window).resize(function(){
              $('.navbar').addClass('solid');
              $('.nav-link').addClass('black');
              $('.navbar-brand').addClass('black');
          })
      }
      else if($(document).scrollTop() > 500) {
          $(window).scroll(function(){
              $('.navbar').addClass('solid');
              $('.nav-link').addClass('black');
              $('.navbar-brand').addClass('black');
          })
      }
      else{
          $('.navbar').removeClass('solid');
          $('.nav-link').removeClass('black');
          $('.navbar-brand').removeClass('black');
      }
   })
}
```

Comment: Do you have a working fiddle or codeply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
$(window).on("load resize scroll", function(e){
    if($(document).width() < 700 || $(document).scrollTop() > 500){ 
        $('.navbar').addClass('solid');
        $('.nav-link').addClass('black');
        $('.navbar-brand').addClass('black');
    } 
    else {
        $('.navbar').removeClass('solid');
        $('.nav-link').removeClass('black');
        $('.navbar-brand').removeClass('black');
    }
});
```

Edit: Or just add one more condition if you want to have it only on scroll pass 500:

```
$(window).on("load resize scroll", function(e){
    if(($(document).width() < 700 && $(document).scrollTop() > 500)
       || $(document).scrollTop() > 500){ 
        $('.navbar').addClass('solid');
        $('.nav-link').addClass('black');
        $('.navbar-brand').addClass('black');
    } 
    else {
        $('.navbar').removeClass('solid');
        $('.nav-link').removeClass('black');
        $('.navbar-brand').removeClass('black');
    }
});
```

Edit: With the `$(window).on("load resize scroll", function(e){});` you bind the 3 events, another way would be:

```
$(window).bind({
     load:function(){

     },
     resize:function(){

     },
     scroll:function(){

    }
});
```

So on load resize or scroll you check for width and scroll bar position. If your condition are met you have a solid navigation.

Comment: The Best Practice. When you are giving to answer any question. Try to give some explanation what changes do you made or what code do you added to achieve the results.

Comment: Thanks for this help. I actually did something similar but I had the most furious time with it. Never occurred to me to use .on. Thank you so much!